# rails runner throws incorrect error: "config.eager_load is set to nil"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm having a hard time running rails runner (in rails version 4.2.6).

Each of the following commands throw the error "config.eager_load is set to nil" even though this value is properly set in all environment files.

```
bin/rails runner -e "MyClass.my_method"
bundle exec rails runner =e "MyClass.my_method"

bin/rails runner -e "MyClass.my_method" RAILS_ENV=development
bundle exec rails runner =e "MyClass.my_method" RAILS_ENV=development

RAILS_ENV=development bin/rails runner -e "MyClass.my_method"
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails runner -e "MyClass.my_method"
```

What's the proper way to run rails runner?

Comment: Here's the docs on the proper way to run `runner`: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner this implies it might be `bin/rails runner -e development "MyClass.my_method"`

Comment: wow. the docs. thanks. post and i will mark as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the docs on the proper way to run runner: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner this implies it might be

```
bin/rails runner -e development "MyClass.my_method"
```

Note: I always recommend reading all the Rails Guides, If you haven't yet - they are one the best ways to level up on Rails. :)